# Let $S$ be a subset of a group $G$ that contains the identity element $1$ and such that the left cosets $aS$ with $a$ in $G$, partition $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $S$ be a subset of a group $G$ that contains the identity element $1$ and such that the left cosets $aS$ with $a$ in $G$, partition $G$.Prove that $S$ a is a subgroup of $G$.

My try:

For $h$ in $S$, If I show that $hS=S$, then that would imply that $S$ is closed.

Now $hS$ is a partiton of $S$ and contains $h$ since $1$ is in $S$. Also $h$ is in $S$. Hence $h \in S\cap hS$. Moreover both of these are partitions and two partitions are either disjoint or equal. Hence $S=hS$ which says that $S$ is closed.

Does this seem alright??

Thanks!!

Comment: $hS$ is a translate of $S$, not a partition of $S$. One doesn't call $S$ and $hS$ partitions, one calls them cells or parts. Anyway, you've shown that $S$ is closed under multiplication and contains the identity - what about closure under inverses?

Comment: @whacka The same I can show that it contains the inverses. WHy aren't they partitions of $G$?? As $h \in G$ , $hS$ is a left coset.

Comment: A partition of $G$ is a collection of disjoint subsets of $G$. *Each* of the subsets is *not* a partition.

Comment: @Quang... The question says they partition $G$. Else I cann't argue that either they are disjoint or equal

Comment: The problem says $\{hS:h\in G\}$ is a partition of $G$. We don't call a particular subset $hS$ a partition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $x,y\in S$, and consider the sets $x^{-1}S$ and $y^{-1}S$, now remark that $1\in x^{-1}S\cap y^{-1}S$ as $\{aS\}_{a\in G}$ is a partition of $G$, then $x^{-1}S=y^{-1}S$, since $x^{-1}\in x^{-1}S$ we get $x^{-1}\in y^{-1}S$, there exists $s\in S$ such that $x^{-1}=y^{-1}s$, so $yx^{-1}=s\in S$. It follow that $S$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: what else do u think I did??

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam You actually didn't show the same thing.  Hamou shows that $S$ satisfies the subgroup criterion.  All your argument does is establish that $S$ is closed.  When $G$ is infinite, this does not guarantee that $S$ is a subgroup.  For instance, take $G= \mathbb Z$ and $S = \mathbb N$.  Though I will grant that in the comments you say you also show that $S$ is closed under inversion.

Comment: @ShawnO'Hare.. I meant by the same arguement, I can show that the inverses belong to the set.

Comment: @Hammou Do you use that to conclue that $x^{-1} \in S$ ?

Comment: @Hamou Your last formula should be $yx^{-1}=s\in S$ (which doesn't ruin the argument).

Comment: @egreg But what part of the subgroup criterion is he showing here ? Is it the fact that: $\forall x \in S, x^{-1} \in S$

Comment: @Carpediem The argument shows that, for all $x,y\in S$, $yx^{-1}\in S$. Hence $S$ is a subgroup, being also non empty. If you wish, just take $y=1$ and this shows that $x^{-1}\in S$ whenever $x\in S$.

Comment: @egreg Without using the above proof, can you explain to me how to show that $x^{-1} \in S$ ?

Comment: @Carpediem Let $x\in S$; then $1\in S\cap x^{-1}S$, so $x^{-1}S=S$, which implies that $x^{-1}=x^{-1}1\in S$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16844/discussion-between-carpediem-and-egreg).

Answer (score 1):

It was difficult to follow your argument, but I think you got it right.
My try:
We will prove that S is closed under multiplication. Let a,b∈S be arbitrary. Since ab∈aS, it will be sufficient to prove that aS=S. Since e∈S, we have a=ae∈aS. By assumption, we also have a∈S=eS. Since aS and eS are both cells of the partition, they are either equal or disjoint. So the fact that they both contain aimplies that aS=eS=S.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a,b$ be two elements of $S$ different from $e$, by definition of cosets, $ab \in aS$, since $a \in S$ and $a=ae \in aS$, $S$ and $aS$ are not disjoint, so they have to be identical, hence $ab \in aS=S$. *Closure* is proved.

*Identity* is in $S$ already.

Suppose there exists $a \in S$ such that $a^{-1} \notin S$, then $a^{-1}S$ would be a coset disjoint from $S$, and yet $e=a^{-1}a \in a^{-1}S$, hence $S$ and $a^{-1}S$ have a common element, contradiction. Ergo $a^{-1}$ must be in $S$, *inverse* is proved. $\square$