# Let $1\in S\subseteq G$ such that the left cosets $aS$ with $a \in G$ partition the group $G$. Prove that $S\le G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am a complete beginner at group theory and I was looking at the following problem.

> Let $S$ be a subset of a group $G$ that contains the identity element $1$ and such that the left cosets $aS$ with $a \in G$ partition $G$.Prove that $S$ a is a subgroup of $G$.

I tried the following:

If we want to show that $S$ is a subgroup of $G$, then we need to satisfy the following:

- $S \subseteq G$
- $1 \in S$
- $a,b\in S \implies ab \in S$
- $\forall a\in S,\, \exists a^{-1} \in S,\, aa^{-1}=a^{-1}a=1$

I know that $S$ is a subset of $G$ so the first requirement is satisfied. It is also given that $1 \in S$, so the second requirement is satisfied.

To prove closure under composition (3), suppose $p,q \in S$. Then $ap,aq \in aS$. We want to show that $a(pq) \in aS$ as well, for some arbitrary $a \in S$.

If we let $b = ap$ and $c = aq$, we have $a^{-1}b = p$ and $a^{-1}c = q$. Left multiplying the equations gives $pq = a^{-1}ba^{-1}c$. since $a^{-1} \in G$, I can say that $pq$ is in another partition $a^{-1}S$, and so it must be the case that $pq \in a^{-1}S$.

Now this is where I'm stuck because I want to get rid of that $a^{-1}$ in front of the $S$, but I don't know how. I've also read this question here [Let $S$ be a subset of a group $G$ that contains the identity element $1$ and such that the left cosets $aS$ with $a$ in $G$, partition $G$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905672/let-s-be-a-subset-of-a-group-g-that-contains-the-identity-element-1-and-su), but I can't understand what the top answer is trying to argue at all, even after reading the comments below it.

Can I please have some help with this problem?

Comment: Note that, if $1\in S$, you need to show that $ab^{-1}$ lies in $S$ for all $a,b\in S$ for it to be a subgroup. That should reduce your work a little. But my guess, say for $a,b\in S$ implies $ab\in S$, is to suppose false. Then $abS\neq S$, and so is some other coset. Then try to find an element in the intersection of two cosets.

Comment: To prove closure, you may try something like this. Let $a, b \in S$. Then $a = a \cdot 1 \in a S$, so $a S = S$, and clearly $a b \in a S$. As to inverses, if $a \in S$, then $1 = a^{-1} a \in a^{-1} S$, so $a^{-1}  \in a^{-1} S = S$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti How can you say that $aS = S$ so simply?

Comment: Because $a \in S \cap a S$, and the cosets of $S$ form a partition. So if two cosets have an element in common, they are the same coset.

Comment: @BrianMoehring But I thought that if all $aS$ partitions $G$, then every $aS \cap bS = \emptyset$ because each left coset forms a partition on $G$. How is it that two cosets have an element in common?

Comment: @Kookie, please review the [definition of a partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set).

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Yeah, that's what I was thinking. Also I kinda see it now. Also, just to clarify, you could say that $ab \in aS$ because if $a \in S$, then since $S$ is a subset of group $G$, so $a \in G$ and hence $ab \in aS = S$?

Comment: Please note that in Maths if you do not speak explicitly of *two distinct* cosets, but just say *two* cosets, they need not be distinct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111561/discussion-between-kookie-and-andreas-caranti).

Comment: Sorry, my time is running out. Just another comment. $a S = \{ a b : b \in S \}$, that is why if $b \in S$, then $a b \in a S$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti got it. Thanks!

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution posted in August 8, 2020, is not correct.
The error/gap is in the sentence
**Thus $st^{-1}=ar$ for some $r\in S$, so that $s=a(rt)\in aS$.**

The problem is that we don't know $a(rt)\in aS$, since we don't know $rt\in S$.

Let me repair that solution. I will use the same notation.
Assume that $S\subseteq G$, $1\in G$,
and $\Pi=\{gS\;|\;g\in G\}$ is a partition of $G$.
Given $s, t\in S$, we argue that $st^{-1}\in S$.

Since $\Pi$ is a partition of $G$, there exists $a\in G$
with $st^{-1}\in aS$. Hence, there exists $r\in S$ such that
$st^{-1}=ar$, which yields $s=art\in arS$. Now $s\in S\cap arS$,
implying that $S\cap arS\neq \emptyset$, so $S=arS$.
Now $ar\in aS$ (since $r\in S$) and $ar=ar1\in arS$
(since $1\in S$), hence $aS\cap arS\neq\emptyset$.
This yields $aS=arS\;(=S)$.
This completes the argument, since now $st^{-1}\in aS=arS=S$.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test#:%7E:text=In%20abstract%20algebra%2C%20the%20one,is%20also%20in%20the%20subset.).

We have $1\in S$, so $S\neq \varnothing $. We are given that $S\subseteq G$.

Let $s,t\in S$. We aim to show that $st^{-1}\in S$.

Suppose $st^{-1}\notin S$. Since $S\subseteq G$ and the cosets of $S$ partition $G$, we have some $a\in G$ such that $a\notin S$ with $st^{-1}\in aS$. Thus $st^{-1}=ar$ for some $r\in S$, so that $s=a(rt)\in aS$. But $s\in S$, so $s\in S\cap aS$. Thus $S=aS$ by definition of a partition, so, since $1\in S$, we have $a\in S$, a contradiction.

Hence $S\le G$.