# If the cosets of $S\subseteq G$ partition $G$, must $S$ be a coset of a subgroup of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, set-partition

If $G$ is a group and $H\le G$ is a subgroup, then the left (or right) cosets of $H$ partition $G$. If $S\subseteq G$ is a left [right] coset of $H$, then the left [right] cosets of $S$ also partition $G$ (as they are precisely the left [right] cosets of $H$). Note that here I consider any set of the form $gS:=\{gs\mid s\in S\}$ for some $g\in G$ to be a **coset of $S$**, regardless of whether $S$ is a subgroup.

For the reverse direction, suppose $S\subseteq G$ is any subset whose cosets partition $G$. Simple counterexamples show that $S$ need not be a subgroup; but if we impose $e\in S$, then $S\le G$ follows, as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3783876/let-1-in-s-subseteq-g-such-that-the-left-cosets-as-with-a-in-g-partition).

It seems natural to me, then that the following might hold:

> Let $G$ be a group and $S\subseteq G$ be an arbitrary subset whose left [right] cosets partition $G$. Then $S$ is a left [right] coset of a subgroup of $G$, i.e., $S=gH$ for some $g\in G$ and $H\le G$.

Is this true? Please help me out with a proof or counterexample. (This is not a homework exercise, I'm just asking out of curiosity.)

Comment: What is the meaning of "partition $G$"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's suppose without loss of generality that the left cosets of $S$ partition $G$. So, for some coset $gS$ of $S,$ we have $e \in gS$. Now, note that the cosets of $gS$
are precisely the cosets of $S$. To see this, note that if $h(gS)$ is a coset of $gS,$ then $h(gS) = (hg)S$ is also a coset of $S$; similarly, if $hS$ is a coset of $S,$ then $hS = (hg^{-1})(gS)$ is also a coset of $gS$.

So, since the cosets of $S$ partition $G,$ the cosets of $gS$ also partition $G.$ By assumption $gS$ is a subset of $G$ containing the identity $e$, so by the answer you linked $gS$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Clearly, $S = g^{-1}(gS)$ is a coset of $gS,$ hence $S$ is a coset of a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Great! So the conjecture is true. I wonder why this nice characterization of group partitions is rarely stated? (Or maybe it is often stated and I just haven't seen it.)

Comment: @WillG . I don't think it is stated often. It is a kind of converse to "The cosets of a subgroup partition the group". Much of group theory is on the properties of subgroups & their cosets, not so much on whether some subset is a subgroup or coset of one.

Comment: An application: Theorem (Poincare). If $H,K$ are left-finite subgroups of the group $G$ (that is, if the sets of left cosets of $H$ and of $K$ are finite) then $H\cap K$ is left-finite. This has an elementary proof. Or  (to apply the Q) we can easily see that the set of left cosets of any member of $P= \{h\cap k:h\in G/H\land k\in G/K\}\setminus \{\emptyset\}$ forms a partition of $G,$ and  $H\cap K\in P.$ Therefore $P=G/(H\cap K).$